# Footnote about corresponding author

Tags: footnotes

I have recently written a paper with another author and I am corresponding author in this. So, How i made a footnote about it?
**Edit:**

```
\begin{document}

\title{S{*}S}[![output image][1]][1]

\author{Aninda and Sayan}

\maketitle
\footnote{1 is the corresponding author}.
```

Now, when I do that I want to get a symbolic mark (like `Sayan^{1}`) and also at the end of the page "^{1} 1 is the corresponding author", but I don't want "1" written at the start of the article. How do I do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it's not enough. There is no way someone can answer without knowing what class you are using. You ought to post a _complete_ example, not just a code snippet.

Comment: Actually I use Lyx in general, so I don't know about any "document class" or "code snippet". These are all new to me. Please elaborate.

Comment: I am using ```\documentclass{amsart}